# initializing virtualenvwrapper on Mac (10.6.8) for Django

Tags: django, macos, osx-snow-leopard, virtualenvwrapper, initializing

I want to use Django and create virtual environments. I don't quite understand the initializing steps documentation on the virtualenvwrapper website. I've installed virtualenvwrapper in  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages. I've already installed XCode, Homebrew and Posgres as well.

The documentation tells me to:

> $ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
>
> $ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
>
> $ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>
> $ mkvirtualenv env1`

I'm especially confused about the first line. Is it telling me that I need to **create** a project folder named 'WORKON_HOME' and export it into another folder called 'Envs'? (I've searched for both folders on my mac but didn't find them). And then in the second line I make another directory 'WORKON_HOME'?
If you have suggestions or links to better explanations/tutorials, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this 3 lines in your `~/.bash_profile` file:-

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/work
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

The `$HOME` environment variable points to your user's home. Also known as the tilda "~", i.e. `/Users/your_osx_username/`.

`WORKON_HOME` is the new environment variable that you are assigning by using the `export` call in your `~/.bash_profile` file.  This is where all your newly created virtualenv directories will be kept.

`PROJECT_HOME` is where you normally place all your custom project directories manually. Nothing to do with your virtualenvs per say but just an easy reference point for you to cd to using the `cd $PROJECT_HOME` syntax.

`which virtualenvwrapper.sh` points to the location where the bash script `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is located and hence when you source it, the functions in that bash script becomes available for your `mkvirtualenv` calls.

Whenever you open a "new shell" (new tab, close your current tab after you first update your `~/.bash_profile` file), all these environment variables and bash functions will be thus available in your shell.

When we create a new virtualenv using the `mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 --distribute my_new_virtualenv_1`, what actually happens is that a new directory called `my_new_virtualenv_1` containing a symlink to your global python2.7 is being created and new python site-packages sub-directory  are created in your `~/.virtualenvs/` directory.  Reference:-

```
calvin$ mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 --distribute my_new_virtualenv_1
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/local/bin/python2.7
New python executable in my_new_virtualenv_1/bin/python
Installing distribute..........................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip................done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/my_new_virtualenv_1/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/my_new_virtualenv_1/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/my_new_virtualenv_1/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/my_new_virtualenv_1/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/my_new_virtualenv_1/bin/get_env_details
```

So if you do

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/my_new_virtualenv_1
calvin$ tree -d
.
├── bin
├── include
│   └── python2.7 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
└── lib
    └── python2.7
        ├── config -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config
        ├── distutils
        ├── encodings -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings
        ├── lib-dynload -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
        └── site-packages
            ├── distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg
            │   ├── EGG-INFO
            │   └── setuptools
            │       ├── command
            │       └── tests
            ├── pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
            │   ├── EGG-INFO
            │   └── pip
            │       ├── commands
            │       └── vcs
            └── readline
```

You will see this directory structure in it.

Note of course that you are using `Envs` and I am using `.virtualenvs` to act as the virtual env holding directory.

Comment: Thank you Calvin. I tried following your directions but my terminal gave me the following error: 'code' Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader.'code' Do you know what might be going on?

Comment: How did you install your `virtualenvwrapper` by the way?  `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: I suspect that your `python` version might still be the default apple-shipped `python` which is python 2.7.1.  You should try to install python 2.7.3 first, which can be done via macports with `sudo port install python2.7` and then select this new python 2.7.3 as default with `sudo port select --set python python27` and followed by setting your `PATH` correctly.  Similar set-up here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader