# Virtualenv : packages lost after restart

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I installed some packages using pip on my virtualenv and got everything running at once :

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/projects
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.s
$ mkvirtualenv pa
```

After this I installed some packages, they ran perfectly, I sat in the morning to work on these, None of the packages are there . Is there anything wrong that I am doing ?

**Update :**

This is the error I am getting if I try to create another env :

```
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
```

Comment: I'm not sure how virtualenvwrapper works, but try without it, perhaps?

Comment: I have to test different versions so that is not an option now

Comment: maybe you're using different branch?

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi: Not without virtualenv; without virtualenvwrapper. Just `virtualenv create <some directory>` and then use `<some directory>/bin/*` instead of the usual ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should write export at your .bashrc file, so it can get active when you run your terminal. In your ~/projects file there could be another file that holds only the envs in this case your export has to point to that file.

This is my .bashrc setting

> export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/DEV/Envs # My directory to envs
>
> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>
> export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME # Tell pip to create its virtualenvs in $WORKON_HOME.
>
> export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true # Tell pip to automatically use the currently active virtualenv.
>
> export VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE=true # use distribute

Also see if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512580/2007842