# Python Traceback Error everytime Terminal is opened

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Every time I open terminal, at the very top I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I tried reinstalling virtualenvwrapper as well as `sudo rm -rf venv`

Comment: what happens when you run the following `/usr/bin/python -c "import virtualenvwrapper"`? Perhaps you have multiple pythons installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Looks a whole lot like this (solved) question:

[Python Virtualenv - No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11507186/1510289)

Does that help?