# /usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to follow [How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I'm failing at the very earlier stage, due to amount of output, I placed all related information into [Pastebin.com - #1 paste tool since 2002!](http://pastebin.com/zYtjFQuM).

the actual error:

```
root@alexus:~# echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
root@alexus:~# source ~/.bashrc
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
root@alexus:~#
```

I'm following how to to the teeth, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `pip install virtualenvwrapper --upgrade` ? If that won't work, please follow this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader

Comment: @Alexander I just installed `python-pip` and `virtualenv` & `virtualenvwrapper`. Do I still need to run upgrade? I'm doing fresh install.

Comment: After you installed all of the above, just run `sudo apt-get update`, then `virtualenv myproject`. Please make sure that your `pip` version is compatible with your `python` version

Comment: BTW, I've never installed `virtualenvwrapper` and I'm using `uwsgi` with `nginx` on a daily basis. I don't recommend installing it unless it's mandatory for you to use it.

Comment: @Alexander my system is up to date. I actually was able to get it to work by switching `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` from `python3` to `python`. I need both `virtualenvwrapper` _AND_ `uwsgi` for my `django` application.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexander, I was able to fix my issue by changing the line in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

to

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: This worked for me, but in my case I needed to change it to `/usr/bin/python3.6`. It needs to match whatever version you're using.

Comment: Worked after using `sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper` instead of `sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: This line needs to be changed in `~/.bashrc`, right? Maybe add that for noobs like me

Comment: I ls /usr/bin/python and it links to "python2". But my system is ubuntu 20, I thought python 2 did not exist there

Comment: In my case I try use pyenv + virtualenvwrapper (not the standalone one, but the pyenv plugin). So I have changed python -> python3 (oposite as in your answer). Otherwise the plugin wasn't recognized. The other possibility was to do for python2: apt install python-pip, pip install virtualenvwrapper (ie. standard virtualenvwrapper, not the pyenv wrapper).

Comment: @alexus, I installed virtualenv using pip3 and added respective export statements to ./bash_profile. Entris isn bash_profile: export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh. It did not work. But then I installed same using pip and it worked. No changes to bash_profile. Will you please explain why did it work this time?

Comment: Man, you just saved me a ton of hassle. I'd give you 2 upvotes if I could.

Answer (score 105):

I faced similar problem, when using python3 with virtualenvwrapper,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper from pip3,

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

then source it again,

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: This method also worked for me on OSX Mojave. using `sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: I need to use python3 for some LDAP functionality, so this is probably the best route to go for me. I initially used the solution proposed by @alexus, which worked, however I'm not sure deviating from a python3 specific setting is not going to cause issues down the road.

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, the `sudo pip3 install...` command displays `error: externally-managed-environment`, as installing packages globally with pip is now discouraged. The following command worked as a replacement: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install python3-virtualenv python3-virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 37):

I encountered a similar issue with `virtualenvwrapper` complaining not being to find `virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader`. I was able to narrow down to this particular line in my `.bash_profile`

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

as seen below

```
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

After some trial and error, it turns out that a reinstallation of the `virtualenvwrapper` package resolved it. This was a manifest of the fact that I recently upgrade python3 (from version 3.5.2 to 3.6.1) via homebrew and in turn it broke virtualenvwrapper's shell script that hardcoded references to the older version of python3 (in my case it was 3.5.2). In short, this below line should fix it (at least in my case it did).

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: Also I noticed that homebrew or some other installed packages at some point in the past that blew away the symlink at `/usr/local/bin/python3`, so somehow re-brew python3 via homebrew to restore the `/usr/local/bin/python3` also make it work again.

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thanks!

Comment: @Devy you can restore the symlink of `/usr/local/bin/python3` with `brew link python@3.8`

Comment: @Devy thanks man! of all the thread, this worked for me. I had /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python3 correctly setup !

Answer (score 19):

In macOS Sierra,
If you installed `virtualenv` package using `pip3`, 
add following to `.bash_profile`

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

or

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
```

after that every new virtualenvironment you created using `workon myvenv`
uses `python3` as python interpreter

Comment: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)` worked for me

Comment: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)` worked for me as well. I *think* this happened because I have two versions of python (2.7 default and 3). With this command, it picks the right one based on virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours trying to find out what was wrong. In my case I am using **pyenv** so just had to use `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(pyenv which python)`

Answer (score 16):

I had already installed virtualenv so just needed to run

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, there was somehow a mismatch between pip3 and python3 (because I have multiple pythons installed). This worked for me:

```
sudo python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 9):

check your `python3` installation directory:

`which python3`

If installed by *brew* you should get:

`/usr/local/python3`

export python version to be used virtualenvwrapper:

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/python3`

source your shell configuration file:
**bash**

`source .bashrc`

**zsh**

`source .zshrc`

Comment: This one helped me: my export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON was set to `python3`. Changing it to `/usr/bin/python3`resolved the issue

Answer (score 9):

Here is what for me solved

```
Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
```

obtained in creating and activating environments.

In my `.bashrc` I had wrote:

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=python3`

Changing it to:

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)`

solved the problem for me.

NOTE: If you activate an environment and run `which python3`, you will find out that the python run is the one of the environment, not the global one specified in `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 20.04, this solved it. As a rule of thumb: put the full path of your python interpreter, not relative, since it changes while the virtualenv is starting.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote this twice. I tried so. many. other. versions of this suggestion. This is the only one that worked.

Comment: I was scratching my head for a couple of hours until I found this. Definitely need more upvotes. Saved a lot more hours.

Answer (score 8):

> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python

good choice, but you already knew /usr/bin/python is 2.7

If you want to use version 3

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

and logout & login

Answer (score 7):

This error appeared for me after running `brew update` and `brew upgrade` on mac os high sierra.

The issue was resolved by reinstalling virtualenvwrappper i.e. `pip install virtualenvwrapper`.

Answer (score 4):

I've got this error for entirely different reasons, but since I ended up on this thread, I gather somebody might find this useful. So in my case, it turned out that my script was attempting to activate the virtual environment while I was already on it (the `workon` statement is issued from my `.profile` file). And so the solution was to simply `deactivate` the environment first and then run the script.

Comment: Thank you so much, gosh it never crossed my mind

Answer (score 4):

If you're here after a macOS update, and installed python3 via brew, try re-linking your version of python3

- `brew link python@3.8`
- `brew link python@3.9`
- etc

Answer (score 3):

On my computer, I ran `sudo apt install python-pip` and then `pip install virtualenvwrapper` but on my settings, I set it as follows:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.Envs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which -a python3)
source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

That got rid of the error and note that I am using python3 and I use pip3 as my default

Answer (score 2):

I had this warning after a brew upgrade, which updated python3 packages and brew-installed python3.

I found a pip3 and python3 version mismatch [as Evan Thomas hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61024109/9460875):

```
❯ which python3 && python3 --version
/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.8.2

❯ which pip3 && pip3 --version
/usr/local/bin/pip3
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Running `brew link python@3.9` [as snakesNbronies suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719631/9460875) removes the warning.

Comment: You're a hero. I needed to `brew link --overwrite python@3.9`

Answer (score 2):

I found that problem can be reproduced with or without pyenv.
Here checklist how to solve this problem which helps me on Mac with fresh install brew and pyenv:

0. `pyenv install 3.11.1` (or whatever version you need) and global it with command `pyenv global 3.11.1`
1. type `python` and make sure, that it's the same version that you set-up in previous step.
2. install virtualenvwrapper with `python -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`
3. FIRST IMPORTANT! SET THE FIRST VARIABLE CORRECT! `which python` tells you python path to your installed path. Use this path to selected by system python executable to tell `virtualenvwrapper` which python it need to use with variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`.
4. SECOND IMPORTANT! Make sure you execute correct virtualenvwrapper.sh. I use pyenv so I just use virtualenvwrapper in my global version (look for config below)

```bash
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

export PYENV_VERSION="$(pyenv version-name)"
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$HOME/.pyenv/shims/python"


export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel

source ~/.pyenv/versions/$PYENV_VERSION/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# Tell pyenv-virtualenvwrapper to use pyenv when creating new Python environments
export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"

# Set the pyenv shims to initialize
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Comment: Today I encountered this problem again for new user on macos

1) I just paste config to .zshrc (.bashrc in your case)
2) have next error with virtualenvwrapper. There helps to install `pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6 after I installed `vim` and `macvim`
using following:

`brew install vim && brew install macvim`

which I believe was the cause for the problem.

While `workon` worked but always gave an error message as below:

```
 ~ $ workon loom
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
(loom)  ~ $
```

What worked for me finally was:

1. adding `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3` to `.bash_profile`
2. `sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's still having this issue, I followed the top answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512672/getting-attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-mutablemapping-w) to fix a pip3 mismatch with my version of python, then ran `sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper` followed by `source ~/.bashrc`  which resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Got the error after upgrading from Pop!_OS 20.04 to 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

try to install python-is-python3:

1.Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2.Install python-is-python3 deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```