# Trouble with step in setting up virtualenvwrapper for Python

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, zsh

I'm trying to complete the section **Managing Virtual Environments With virtualenvwrapper** [here](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).

I'm up to this section:

> Once it’s installed, we’ll need to activate its shell functions. We can do this by running source on the installed virtualenvwrapper.sh script. When you first install it with pip, the output of the installation will tell you the exact location of virtualenvwrapper.sh. Or you can simply run the following:
>
> `$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
>
> `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
>
> Using that path, add the following three lines to your shell’s startup file. If you’re using the Bash shell, you would place these lines in either the `~/.bashrc` file or the `~/.profile` file. For other shells, like zsh, csh, or fish, you would need to use the startup files specific to that shell. All that matters is that these commands are executed when you log in or open a new shell:
>
> `export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs   # Optional`
>
> `export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects      # Optional`
>
> `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

When using `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`, I got the following result:

`/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Then I use `export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs` and `export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects` with no output, implying success.

And finally, I use `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and get the following result:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.`

`If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.`

I'm not sure precisely what is wrong here, but it should be using Python 3 instead of Python 2:

`python --version` results in `Python 2.7.16`

`python3 --version` results in `Python 3.7.6`

My OS is macOS, and my shell is zsh.

---

### Edit

As suggested in the comments, I followed the **Using Django inside a Python virtual environment** section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment).

This works fine:

`export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs`

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`

`export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel`

However, `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` results in

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper') virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.`

`If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is set properly.`

Comment: It looks like your linked tutorial is missing the exports to point to python3. Check out this [setup guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment) in MDN, go to the Using Django inside a Python virtual environment. You'll see the python3 export and the default env version export. I did it on Ubuntu - not sure of the macOS differences.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere See my edit. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216679/usr-bin-python3-error-while-finding-spec-for-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader) - is that the same issue you are having? Also, what is your which python3 result? My export has the version - `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Yes, it seems like it. I'm attempting the instructions in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799713/6828329 answer. The problem is, for `source .zshrc`, I get `source: no such file or directory: .zshrc`

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Mine is `which python3` gets me `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Ok, I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799713/6828329 answer and did `source ~/.zshrc` and then `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` worked!

Comment: I then proceeded as stated here: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ . 1. `export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs` 2. `export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects` 3. `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` 4. `source ~/.bashrc` 5. `echo $WORKON_HOME` 6. `mkvirtualenv my-new-project` all works when done in this order.

Comment: I hope this will help others who encounter the same issues. Thank you @DaveStSomeWhere for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you forced any other Python version besides your OS default, you should change and make default in OS settings for the newer python version.
I had the same issue just after override my linux default python version and to solve my problem I just changed the default py3 version.