# Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' when I downgrade python3.7 to python3.6

Tags: python

I have been stuck with this problem since last night trying to solve and have tried all recommended solutions here and still didn't work. I am hoping to find a positive suggestion if there is actually any possible method I may not have tried yet. I started experiencing problems with my virtaulenv and virtualwrapper after downgrading my python version from 3.7 to 3.6.

"/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks"

when I tried 'sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper' and 'sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper' I received "Requirements already satisfied".

I also tried "brew unlink python && brew link python" to link them with python3.6 but still it didn't work. Please I will appreciate your help and positiive suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was able to navigate through this using

sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

Then I created another virtual environment using

sudo virtualenv-p python3

source >target folder>/bin/activate

This worked for me

Comment: I don't have a `virtualenv-p`. Where does that come from?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to `./bashrc` fixed this error in my environment.

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

similar to: [/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216679/usr-bin-python3-error-while-finding-spec-for-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader)