# Getting AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping' while using any pip3 command on linux Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, attributeerror

Hey I have installed latest python 3.10 and pip3 on my linux (Zorin os lite 15.3 X64) machine but whenever I try to use any pip3 command I get following error
For example I use the command:

> pip3 freeze

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

This was working fine with python 3.9 but when I updated to 3.10 I started getting this error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Were you able to finally resolve this for yourself? Updating Python to 3.10.1 did not help.

Comment: No, I switched back to version 3.9

Comment: Please see update below - I think we have a solution (or at least a workaround).

Answer (score 37):

The problem is caused by an old version of `pyparsing` that has been vendored into `pkg_resources`, which is now part of `setuptools`.

I think if you install an updated `setuptools`, things will run better:

```
python -m pip install -U setuptools
```

EDIT - After installing my own version of 3.10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, I am having this same issue. And the broken pkg_resources is preventing doing any updates, so your classic Catch-22. To begin chasing down a resolution, I've submitted a ticket on the setuptools Github repo.

EDIT2 - Based on [aid on the setuptools GitHub repo](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2988#issuecomment-1007991935), I did the following steps:

```
# add deadsnake repo (default or nightly)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.10
git clone https://github.com/pypa/setuptools.git && cd setuptools && sudo python3.10 setup.py install
sudo apt install python3.10-distutils
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
```

At this point, I am able to run pip in Python3.10, and create venvs using `python3.10 -m venv virtualenv-dir`.

Comment: Did this work for anyone? I am using python 3.10 installed via pyenv, and it did not work for me. I am also using pipenv in my enviroment if that makes a difference.

Comment: pkg_resources imports packaging, which imports pyparsing. The pyparsing 3.0.5 release included breaking API changes, which were refactored back in in pyparsing 3.0.6. If still not working after updating to pyparsing 3.0.6, please post an issue on pyparsing's GitHub.

Comment: Packaging 21.3 just got pushed to pypi, compatible with the latest pyparsing, so I think these issues should all be sorted if upgrade to latest of both packages.

Comment: @AugustineCalvino - I am seeing this issue now on Ubuntu, working on it. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: No, I was not able to resolve this - I ended up switching to Poetry for this and a few other reasons.

Comment: It work for my case. Ubuntu 16.04 and python3.10.

Comment: Solves the error for python3.10 on Ubuntu18

Comment: solve the error after updating python3.6 to python3.10 on bionic

Comment: This worked for me under WSL Ubuntu-18.04 .

Answer (score 32):

update pip using code bellow

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

Comment: You may need to do: `sudo apt-get install python3.10-distutils` if you get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'`

Answer (score 5):

"Do not install pipenv from apt, it's way too old. Install from pypi."
source: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5469

This solve it for me:

```
sudo apt remove pipenv
pip install pipenv
```

Unfortunately `pipenv`didn't worked out of the box in this console. I had to use:

```
python -m pipenv
```

Or simply start a new terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

I can try to fix it with `pip install request --upgrade`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux mint

```
sudo apt remove pipenv
pip3 install pipenv
```

or

```
sudo apt install pipenv
```

Answer (score -5):

Update pip...collections.MutableMapping has become collections.abc.MutableMapping.

Comment: Actually you want to update python wheel.  If you run into any other issues, the first thing to do is to update to the latest package versions from pypi.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).