# pipenv crashes with an error message as soon as it is started

Tags: python, pipenv

pipenv crashes every time I start it with the message included below. I am running python 3.10.12 on Linux Mint 21.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 621, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1018, in parse_args
    rest = Command.parse_args(self, ctx, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 875, in parse_args
    parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 821, in make_parser
    for param in self.get_params(ctx):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 774, in get_params
    help_option = self.get_help_option(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 26, in get_help_option
    from .import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_pipenv.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 621, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1018, in parse_args
    rest = Command.parse_args(self, ctx, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 875, in parse_args
    parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 821, in make_parser
    for param in self.get_params(ctx):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 774, in get_params
    help_option = self.get_help_option(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 26, in get_help_option
    from .import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I have tried reinstalling pipenv using both pip and apt with exactly the same result.
The arguments supplied to pipenv make no difference to what happens.

Comment: `MutableMapping` was removed from `collections.MutableMapping` in python 3.10. Perhaps check if you pip is up to date.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512672/getting-attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-mutablemapping-w for some suggested actions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943244/attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-mutablemapping)