# virtualenvwrapper mkvirtualenv not working but no errors

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm working through Hitchhiker's Guide to Python's section on virtualenvwrapper, but am having difficulty creating a virtualenv. I don't receive any error when I try to create a virtualenv, but when I try to `workon` it, an error is thrown saying the env doesn't exist. My `WORKON_HOME` is empty. What might be the matter?

```
$ mkvirtualenv test
# NOTHING PRINTS HERE
$ workon test
ERROR: Environment 'test' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv test'.
$ workon
# NOTHING PRINTS HERE
```

Relevant lines from my `.bashrc`, drawing on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader) and the [official installation guide](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Documents/Coding
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Looks like on the docs(https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html) 

the order of commands is different that yours. workon then mkvirtualenv test.

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove I believe they just run `workon` first to show that there are no virtual environments existing at that time, but then after creating a virtual environment with `mkvirtualenv`, `workon` will now show the new environment.

I tried doing it in this order and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I am not familiar with this library but there are other ways to make virtual environments.

Comment: Is `virtualenvwrapper.sh` sourced? `type -a mkvirtualenv`? Run `exec bash -x` and then `mkvirtualenv test` to see where it stops.

Comment: @phd My `bash_profile` includes these lines 

```export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Documents/Coding
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh```

Comment: @phd When following your commands, it stops with these lines:

```+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ virtualenvwrapper_cd /Users/ME/.virtualenvs
+ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
+ builtin cd /Users/ME/.virtualenvs
+ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh test
+ '[' -d /Users/ME/.virtualenvs/test ']'
+ typeset RC=1
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ return 1```

Comment: I suspect the problem in this command: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh test`. It must be `virtualenv`, not `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. You don't set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` env var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the line

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

from my `.bashrc` and re-sourcing the terminal solved the problem. I had mistakenly provided the path to `virtualenvwrapper` instead of `virtualenv` like the `.bashrc` did in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader) I drew from.