# ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper'

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenvwrapper

Since I upgraded to OS X 10.9, I get this message when opening a new terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If
Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that
virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and
that PATH is set properly.
```

The problem seems to be related to virtualenv, but I actually don't need it anymore. So if uninstalling it can solve the problem, I can do it.

Comment: read SO first. question possible is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968914/getting-a-python-virtual-env-error-after-installing-lion, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549824/terminal-issue-with-virtualenvwrapper-after-mavericks-upgrade?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have `virtualenvwrapper`, you can install it using `pip` or you can download the whole tar.zip file from pypi, and then run `python setup.py`. The best method is to use `pip`.

Comment: I tried added using pip but still it gives as error